# Texturing & labeling

Tags: texturing

[image]

I am graphic designer special in awards making 2D & 3D trophies. im my company we are using 3d mex for modeling and keyshot for rendering.

I want to switch to Blender, I have all modeling concepts just I want to rendering something like above picture as sample, material applying to some parts, coloring, texturing and label applying.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). If you're want to learn Blender basics and modeling [start here with the Donut tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U). If you just want to add a texture to your model, [start here with Uwrapping tutorial](https://youtu.be/scPSP_U858k)

Comment: Hello and welcome. What is your question specifically?